# ternary operator causes an error inside if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

Why is this statement causing 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined' ? I thought it'd notice that`und` is undefined and just avoid the line where it tries to make a string out of `und`.
 If I remove `true ||` from 'if' statement it works fine

```
let und = undefined;

if (true || und ? und.toString() === 'anything' : false) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: What is purpose of `true ||` within `if` condition?

Comment: it seems your concept of ternary operators is not clear

Comment: it's different in real code, ternary operator is to avoid other separate statement in my case

Comment: @Teemu Thats why I said *sort of*. I also knew its not the right terminology.

Comment: `if   true?  OR undefined   if "und" is exactly 'anything' else  false?????

Comment: I think correct way would be `if(variable1 || (und && und.toString() === 'anything'))`, considering you do not have hard-coded `true` in `if`

Comment: @IvanMinakov What is purpose of `if (true && (expression))`?

Comment: the 'true' part is different in my code, I just wanted to avoid complexity here and demonstrate the problem of the error which is unclear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This instruction:

```
true || und ? und.toString() === 'anything' : false
```

Will be read as:

```
(true || und) ? und.toString() === 'anything' : false
```

Since the `OR` statement is `true`, `und.toString() === 'anything'` will be executed, **even if** `und` **is** `undefined`.

You need to put parentheses around the ternary operator.

```js
let und = undefined;

if (true || (und ? und.toString() === 'anything' : false)) {
  console.log('Yeah, no error thrown');
}
```

Comment: A complicated way to print `"Yeah, no error thrown"`

Comment: The condition would be  `true` at each evaluation, not reaching second expression, yes?

Comment: this expression always `true`

Comment: @Andreas yes it is indeed, just answering OP's question.

Comment: What exactly is OP's Question?

Comment: @guest271314 You're right, but again, I'm just answering OP's question.

Comment: @guest271314 well the question is why is an error thrown inside the ternary operator, isn't it?

Comment: From perspective here, the question is what  is purpose of `true || (expression)` within `if` condition?

Comment: `Why is this statement causing 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined' ?`

Comment: my question is why the statement causes an error. the 'true' part is different statements in my code, I just wanted to showcase without unnecessary complexity. If that makes any sense

Comment: @Erazihel _"well the question is why is an error thrown inside the ternary operator, isn't it?"_ , _"Why is this statement causing 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined' ?"_  If that is the case how does your answer actually answer the Question?

Comment: @Prozrachniy I've updated my answer, please check the detailed explanations

Comment: @guest271314 I've updated my answer, please check the detailed explanations

Comment: If that's what really happening behind the scenes, that really answers my question, thanks